# Custom CSS and JS not loading on WordPress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

These Enqueue script I want to load these code  on HTML in a specific page. For me its not working. I implement the code by activating child theme

```
    function child_post_themes_styles() {

    wp_enqueue_style( 'reset_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/resetx.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/stylex.css' );

    }
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'child_post_themes_styles' );

    function child_post_themes_js() {

    wp_enqueue_script( 'modernizer_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/modernizerx.js', '', '', false );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'main_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/mainx.js', '', '', false );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery2_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-2.1.1x.js', 'array('jquery')', '', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquerymobile_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.mobilex.custom.min.js', 'array('jquery')', 'jquery2_js', '', true );

    }
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'child_post_themes_js' );
```

Comment: Try use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` instead for in a child theme. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_directory_uri/#comment-1797

Comment: after enqueue. Is there anything else to add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    function child_post_themes_styles() {

    wp_enqueue_style( 'reset_css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/resetx.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style_css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/stylex.css' );

    }
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'child_post_themes_styles' );

    function child_post_themes_js() {

    wp_enqueue_script( 'modernizer_js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/modernizerx.js', '', '', false );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'main_js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/mainx.js', '', '', false );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery2_js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-2.1.1x.js', 'array('jquery')', '', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquerymobile_js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.mobilex.custom.min.js', 'array('jquery')', 'jquery2_js', '', true );

    }
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'child_post_themes_js' );
```

**get_template_directory_uri** will always refer to the parent theme folder for assets.
**get_stylesheet_directory_uri** will refer to the "current" theme folder for assets (which could be the parent or the child, depending on where it is called).

Comment: Thanks very much Sco

Comment: After addding the css file. Header menu alignment problem occurs. Any olution>?

Answer (score 0):

You can create the file functions.php in child theme folder.

After put the function on functions.php file in child theme folder

```html
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'child_post_themes_styles' );
function child_post_themes_styles() {
 wp_enqueue_style( 'reset-css', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/resetx.css' );
 wp_enqueue_style( 'style-css', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/stylex.css' );
 wp_enqueue_script( 'modernizer-js', get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ).'/js/modernizerx.js', array( 'jquery' ), '', false );
 wp_enqueue_script( 'main-js', get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ).'/js/mainx.js', array( 'jquery' ), '', false );
 wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery2-js', get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ).'/js/jquery-2.1.1x.js', array( 'jquery' ), '', true );
 wp_enqueue_script( 'jquerymobile-js', get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ).'/js/jquery.mobilex.custom.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), '', true );
}
```